# Best freely available material on learning probability distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, soft-question

I am looking for a very easy to understand, interesting to 'digest', freely available, 'teach yourself' material on probability distributions which treats it indepth. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to check the webpage of some university professor who has free notes for her/his students. A quick google search points towards http://www.hamilton.ie/ollie/Downloads/ProbMain.pdf and http://www2.aueb.gr/users/demos/pro-stat.pdf. You could also try browsing the Khan Academy courses https://www.khanacademy.org/

Comment: Thanks. I asked as I thought its better to benefit from the experience of those who are well familiar with the literature in this area.

Comment: I am partial to Radically Elementary Probability Theory by Edward Nelson, and just found out that it is available at his webpage https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/books/rept.pdf
However, Neldon's approach to the subject is rather unusual, so it is possible that the book might not be suitable for your purposes.